# How to refresh a liferay portlet?

Tags: javascript, liferay, portlet

I try to create a link refreshing a liferay portlet, but this doesn't work:

```
<a href="javascript:Liferay.Portlet.refresh('#p_p_id_portletname')">link</a>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: is there any error in js console?

Comment: @PankajkumarKathiriya, no there isn't

Comment: Is portlet here a custom portlet? Which version of Liferay you are using? Would you share exact name you are providing as portletname

Comment: No, it is my portlet. Exact name is: customCharts_WAR_CustomCharts_INSTANCE_6QxU. I am using Liferay 5.2.3.

Comment: Make sure, you add _ at the end. For example: `#p_p_id_customCharts_WAR_CustomCharts_INSTANCE_6QxU_`, also use onclick attribute instead of href

Comment: @PankajkumarKathiriya, I forgot about _ at the end! It works! Why do you suggest to use onclick instead of href? What is wrong with href?

Comment: href is not recommended to be used with java script as argument. Its better approach to use onclick when you are calling any javascript function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add extra _ (underscore) at the end.

e.g.
`Liferay.Portlet.refresh("#p_p_id_customCharts_WAR_CustomCharts_INSTANCE_6QxU_")`

Also, Its good practice to use onclick attribute instead of href for calling javascript.